# How to fix CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE problem while writing a file with rioxarray?

Tags: gdal, rasterio, rioxarray

I get this warning when I try to write out a raster using rioxarray:

```
Free disk space available is 0 bytes, whereas 1152072000 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.
```

I know this is a GDAL thing, which solutions are well-documented for. However, rioxarray is wrapped over GDAL, and I'm having trouble finding a way to overwrite the error. There is certainly enough disk space to write the file.

Answer (score 0):

Rasterio is just stuff on top of GDAL, where the issue you mention arises. You can pass the GDAL configuration to rasterio as

```py
with rasterio.Env(CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE="NO"):
    rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
    rds.rio.to_raster(...)
```

(I don't know whether you need to pass `"NO"` or `False`. You can read more about this [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/configuration.html#gdal-option-co).

Comment: It's rioxarray, not rasterio

Comment: rioxarray wraps rasterio wraps GDAL. Have you tried having your rioxarray call within the first  context manager? You can also pass an already opened rasterio dataset to rioxarray.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first option. Do you mean, opening with rioxarray and then using rasterio.Env to deactivate the disc space check? I think I did this and still had errors

Comment: Updated the example to wrap rioxarray code.